# Salvar imagem de um site com o PHP?

Tags: php, imagem

Como eu salvo uma imagem de um determinado site em uma pasta do meu site usando o PHP?

E como ficaria para redimensionar essa imagem?

usei dessa forma mas nao deu certo: file_put_contents($diretorio, file_get_contents($url));
também tentei com a função copy e não obtive resultado algum..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua tentativa com `file_get_contents` só funciona se o `php.ini` estiver setado desta forma:

```
allow_url_fopen=true
```

Mas se estiver habilitado, nem precisa de `file_get_contents`, já pode simplificar com `copy`:

```
copy( $urlOrigem, $arquivoDestino );
```

Caso não queira ou não possa ativar o `allow_url_fopen`, uma alternativa é o `cURL`:

```
$curl = curl_init( $urlOrigin );
$file = fopen( $fileDestination, 'wb' );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );
fclose( $file );
```

Neste segundo caso, a extensão `cURL` tem que estar habilitada.

Sobre redimensionar imagem com PHP, **[já temos algumas respostas no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=redimensionar+php)**.